# How do I use OpenVPN for all traffic other than ports 80 and 22 (inbound and outbound)?

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

I use a dynamic DNS service which is sent ip address updates from my router. In router settings, ports 22 and 80 are forwarded to my server at 192.168.1.10. I have a webserver and sshd running on my server. From outside my local network, I can go to mydomain.dyndns.org, or ssh into my server.  This works fine until I connect to OpenVPN. When I connect my server to my OpenVPN provider, I can no longer ssh into my server from outside my local network. Both http and ssh timeout.  Even if I cut out the dyndns stuff and just use the WAN IP, it still times out with OpenVPN connected, and works when I stop OpenVPN.

My OpenVPN provider (I do not control) that pushes routes to me (the client). Specifically, when connecting to the openvpn, the following commands are run:

```
/sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.15.0.74 pointopoint 10.15.0.73 mtu 1500
/sbin/route add -net 141.255.164.66 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1
/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.15.0.73
/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.15.0.73
/sbin/route add -net 10.15.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.15.0.73
```

and the added routes are removed with `del` when the vpn connection closes.

The problem is, this routes *everything* though the VPN.  Instead, I would like my server to use the openvpn for all traffic other than ports 80 and 22 (inbound and outbound). i.e. I'd like to be able to connect to my server using http and ssh.

I believe similar questions have been asked, but they seem to be all routing specific ports throught the VPN and everything else, not though the vpn.  I have not been able to adapt them for my purposes.

EDIT:

My router is 192.168.1.1 (a dd-wrt router). My guess is that ssh/http traffic should be marked and set to use 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway. However, im not sure how.

EDIT 2:

Following advice of leucos, I tried the following:

```
root@FILESERVER:~# curl ipecho.net/plain; echo
###.###.135.118
root@FILESERVER:~# echo "Connecting to OpenVPN in other terminal"
Connecting to OpenVPN in other terminal
root@FILESERVER:~# curl ipecho.net/plain; echo
###.###.164.93
root@FILESERVER:~# echo "1 NOVPN" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
root@FILESERVER:~# ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev p4p1 table NOVPN
root@FILESERVER:~# ip route show table NOVPN
default via 192.168.1.1 dev p4p1 
root@FILESERVER:~# ip rule add from all fwmark 0x1 lookup NOVPN
root@FILESERVER:~# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
root@FILESERVER:~# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
root@FILESERVER:~# curl ipecho.net/plain; echo
###.###.164.93
```

Now I'm not *exactly* sure how ipecho.net works, but my guess is that it has received something from ###.###.164.93, which (I guess) means port 80 traffic was *not* routed through p4p1 (my native interface), but instead was routed through tun0 (setup by OpenVPN). Trying to connect from outside my network also continued to timeout.

Comment: Ask the provider to not push the default route?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I can use `route-nopull` for that. Then what? :-)

Comment: What is [the _actual_ problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912) you are trying to solve?

Comment: I would like my server to use the openvpn for all traffic other than ports 80 and 22 (inbound and outbound).

Comment: You said that already, and it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sorry, I'm not sure how I can be more clear. In response to your link, I specifically asked how to route traffic (my problem) rather than something like "How do I mark outbound traffic?" (one possible solution), so I do not believe I've fallen into the "XY Problem"

Comment: You can be more clear by explaining what you hope to accomplish, why you are doing this, etc.

Comment: info added to top of question

Answer (score 1):

"Normal" routing decisions are based on destination and routing table prefixes and masks. If you want to make routing decisons based on other data (e.g. TCP ports), you have to use `ip rule`.

With `ip rule`, you can basically ask the kernel to use an alternative routing table when some condition occurs. You typically use packet marking in iptables for this.

Here is an example, untested, you might want to try this (don't play with this if you only have a remote connection to your server !).

```
# Create an alternate routing table
echo "1 NOVPN" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# Create the routes for this table
# Actually, you just want to set the default gateway
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table NOVPN

# Check results with
ip route show table NOVPN

# Now tell the kernel that this routing table should be used when 
# a packet waiting to be routed has a specific "mark"
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x1 lookup NOVPN

# Then mark all the required packets with the same mark use above
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1 
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Good luck.

EDIT:

You might need to adjust your source address too :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.10
```

If it doesn't work, check what happens with :

```
tcpdump -enieth0 port 80
```

(I assume in my replies that the proper outbount Ethernet interface is eth0)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, however it did not work. I will post more in the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong chain... Answer edited, can you try again ?

Comment: I rebooted, and then tried again with the changes. Exactly the same results as before.

Comment: Sorry, probably wrong chain again. POSTROUTING, as the name suggests, happens after the routing decision has been taken ! Answer edited.

Comment: Same results - doesn't work. I will post the `tcpdump` when I'm not at work (I don't want to mess with this stuff remotely)

Answer (score 0):

This causes all traffic to go via the VPN

```
/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.15.0.73
/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.15.0.73
```

Did you perhaps specify this in the configuration file? According to the [OpenVPN documents](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect) the relevant configuration directive is `redirect-gateway`

Comment: I do not have control of the vpn server, and did not set it up. I can reject the route directives from the server, but then what?